# How to invoke a method on SOA web service from Python?

Tags: python, web-services, sockets, soa, invoke

I have a locally development Box where I have configured Python. 
There is another server on different network. A SOA web service is located in there. They exposed an application.

There are methods in the application to execute several operations. Like `getAssetDetails()`, `getPhonenumberByContact()` etc. Now I want to use those methods from my local using python by sending and receiving XMLs. What do I really need to access those methods ?

I know bit of scripting but beginner to this  field. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Use Python 2.7 (64/32) depends on your system type
# System 64, Python 64, suds 64 OR System 32, Python 32, suds 32
# Install SUDS, pip install suds or download and install
from suds.client import Client

xml_request = '''your request xml'''
def yourfunctionname(_xml_request):
    url = 'http://wsdl_url?wsdl'
    client = Client(url)
    xml = Raw(_xml_main)
    responsedata = (client.service.yourMethodName(__inject={'msg': xml}))
    return respdata

getData=yourfunctionname(xml_request)
for i in getData:
    print(i)
```